# Get data from mysql to input tag when value of select is ID

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have MySQL table  "names":

```
  id |    name   |   country  |    age  
  1  |    Mark   |   Germany  |     20  
  2  |    Jack   |    UK      |     23  
  3  |    Mary   |    US      |     32  
  4  |   Suzan   |   Italy    |     15
```

What I need is :

- When I select 2, I want set value of input tag to 23
- When I select 4, I want set value of input tag to 15

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <select  id="name" name="name"  required  >
            <option></option>
            <option  value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" >
                <?php echo $row['name']; ?> - <? echo $row['country']; ?> - <? echo $row['age']; ?>  
            </option> 
        </select>
        <input type="number"  id="age" name="age" value=" " placeholder=" age" required>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please format your question properly and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: don't get exactly what you want to say

Comment: Ok Mehul Kuriya ... can you improve code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things you have to do:

First you put the value you want to use as value in the value from the option.

To simplify the example see HTML the value of the option is the value you need! So no reason to set there an ID and get the age.. even if that is possible there is not reason here to do that..

```js
var mySelect = document.getElementById("name");
mySelect.addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction()  {
 document.getElementById("age").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value;
};
```

```html
<select  id="name" name="name"  required  >
    <option  value="1" >
        name1 - country1 - age 1
    </option>
    <option  value="2" >
        name2 - country2 - age 2
    </option>
    <option  value="3" >
        name3 - country3 - age 3
    </option>
    <option  value="4" >
        name4 - country4 - age 4
    </option>
</select>
<input type="number"  id="age" name="age" value="" placeholder=" age" required>
```

Then, seccond: To get that HTML like above you might need to write something like this in PHP

```
<select  id="name" name="name"  required  >

    <?php
        // assuming you get your MySQL results in a array called $rows
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            echo '<option  value="'.$row['age'].'">'.
                     $row['name'] . ' - ' . $row['country'] . ' - ' . $row['age']
            .'</option>';
        }
    ?>

</select>
<input type="number"  id="age" name="age" value="" placeholder=" age" required>
```

Comment: Thank to answer this question. .but I need to display real age no Id in input tag

Comment: @جمانةالصافي it is the age! See this line: `<option  value="'.$row['age'].'">`. In input it will show the value from the option. So just use the age as value in the option and not the ID